# Ordering with addition on extended real numbers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Does $$a+b\leq a+c<a+d \Longrightarrow b\leq c<d$$ for all $a$ and all finite $b,c,d$ in the extended real numbers $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$?

By replacing $a$ with the symbol $\infty$ this is definitely false but intuitively by using $a$ instead they are the “same infinity” and can be cancelled? If this isn’t the case does that mean that $a-a=0$ doesn’t hold for all extended real numbers $a$?

Answer (score 1):

This inequality holds for $a\in \mathbb{R}$, but not for $\{+\infty, -\infty\}$. For finite numbers, $a-a=0$ holds, but not for infinite quantities.